# How to convert an T-SQL SmallDateTime value to an Excel datevalue in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, excel, date

I've seen in another thread how to convert an Excel date value to a T-SQL `SmallDateTime` value...

```
(SELECT DATEADD(d, 36464, '1899-12-31')
```

OR

```
(SELECT CAST(36464 - 2 as SMALLDATETIME)
```

I would like to do the reverse, still using T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
select datediff(d,'1899-12-31',mydate)
```

but I don't have an easy way of testing this currently.

Also the conversion is automatic when importing or exporting between Excel and SQL server so I'm not sure when you'd use it?